# How to use xcode to debug and step through llvm source code

Tags: xcode, llvm, lldb

I am currently using Xcode to build llvm source. Once built, I use lldb to step through the execution of specific llc binary through the console.

How can i use Xcode to set breakpoints and step through the code in xcode itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was new to Xcode and using ALL_BUILD in Xcode as target. Changed the target to llc, added the required file.bc as argument by "Edit Scheme" and now I can step through the execution!